# iBeacon, Is possible to get list of BLE devices?

Tags: iphone, ipad, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I have bought 5 BLEs from sensor tag, I Downloaded some iBeacon detection code.

But I do not know UUID of the 5 BLEs. Do I Need to put the UUID in my iBeacon detection code?

How Can I get the bluetooth device list using iBeacon code?

Answer (score 1):

While you can use CoreBluetooth to do an LE scan and see all nearby iBeacons, the info you get back about each iBeacon is not very useful -- iOS blocks you from being able to read the iBeacon identifiers, including the ProximityUUID.  See My blog post about this [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html).

So the bottom line is that while you can see unknown Proximity UUID iBeacon devices with iOS, you cannot even be sure the devices you see are iBeacons at all.

Android and OSX Mavericks do not have this restriction, so if you have access to one of those devices, try my company's [iBeacon Locate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.ibeaconlocate) or [ScanBeacon](http://www.radiusnetworks.com/scanbeacon-app.html) products, which will read your identifiers for you.

Answer (score 0):

Is impossible, at lest no way to get this list via public API, you must know the UUIDs before ranging

Comment: That is incorrect - You can write code to scan for peripherals using the CoreBluetooth Framework.

Comment: yea, scan for peripherals yes, **but not for iBeacon UUID**

Comment: iBeacon is built on top of CoreBluetooth. iBeacons are a particular kind of peripherals. iBeacons are peripherals.

Comment: this question, as i understand, about iBeacon proximity UUIDs, that is need for iBeacon functionality, not for BLE peripherals in general

Comment: If do CoreBluetooth cant get notification to fast. iBeacon is background fasting too. I want Background fast.